# How do I use mariabackup to do point in time restores?

Tags: backup, mariadb

So I've read about the basic way that I can backup my mariadb using mariadb backup...

What I don't understand is how to make it point in time......

So I want to restore using mariadbackup full and incrementals and then what do I use to get to the point in time of the crash....

SO how do I incorporate the binary logs? or redo logs?

This is where I'm lost.